# Configure autocomplete for the first argument, leave the others alone

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I have a utility that takes a load of different arguments. For now, I want to autocomplete the first argument, but leave all the others to fall through to normal autocompletion. How do I do that?

```
function _my_autocomplete_()
{
    case $COMP_CWORD in
        1) COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "$(get_args_somehow)" -- ${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}));;
        *) # What goes here?
    esac
}

complete -F _my_autocomplete_ mycommand
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently I completely missed your question.  The answer is that there's no well-defined "normal autocompletion."  However, if you know what sort of thing you'd like it to complete (files, aliases, pids, variable names, etc.), you can give one or more flags to `compgen`.  See [this compgen manual page](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/compgen1.html), specifically the `-A` options under `complete` (they're the same).  E.g. if you want to complete file names, you would use this:

```
compgen -f -- "${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
```

If you want to complete commands (incl. aliases, functions, etc.), you can use this:

```
compgen -back -A function -- "${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
```

---

Use [`$COMP_CWORD`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) to get the index of the word being completed. If the index isn't 1, set `$COMPREPLY` to `()` and return.

```
COMP_CWORD

    An index into ${COMP_WORDS} of the word containing the current 
    cursor position. This variable is available only in shell functions
    invoked by the programmable completion facilities
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with bash completion. Does setting `COMP_REPLY` to `()` mean “default completions” rather than “no completions”? I don't see any mention of `COMP_REPLY` in the manual.

Comment: @Gilles My bad, it's `$COMPREPLY` without the underscore. Setting `COMPREPLY=()` does tell `bash` not to offer any completion, I just checked to be sure.

Comment: Ok. That's not what Dominic wanted: he wants the default completion to happen for the other arguments.

Comment: Oh, I see.  There is no 'default' completion, but you can get certain types (folders, functions, variables) with a command, I think it's certain flags on compgen.  I'm traveling right now, I'll update when I get home.

Comment: @Kevin - apologies for taking a while to get back to you. I want to complete filenames really. I've tried `COMPREPLY=($(compgen -f -- ${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}));;`, but if I type `/hom` [tab] I get `/home ` (with a trailing space) instead of `/home/` allowing me to tab my way to whatever path I want. Any ideas?

Comment: @DominicRodger in the `complete -F _my_autocomplete_ mycommand` command, add `-o filenames`.

Comment: To complete shell functions, `-A function` (singular) should be used instead of `-A functions`.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is incorrect. `compgen -f` comes close to the default behavior, but it's not quite the same (try autocompleting the name of a directory to see the difference).

The answer to `# What goes here?` is very simple: `compopt -o default`